# EC2 instance can not access in browser

Tags: django, python-2.7, amazon-ec2, ip-address, django-manage.py

I created one EC2 instance for Django project with Ubuntu server.

I installed all required package of django, python etc successfully.

But when I am trying through ssh with private ip : python manage.py runserver xxx.xx.xx.xx:8983 its running, but when I am trying to load it through browser its gives as error : "The Connecion has timed out"

I have assigned VPC security group to this instance.

Also, I try with public IP address through SSH:  : python manage.py runserver XXX.XX.XX.XX:8983
It gave error as follows :

Validating models...

0 errors found
July 15, 2015 - 22:34:10
Django version 1.6.7, using settings 'conf.settings.local'
Starting development server at http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:8983/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Error: That IP address can't be assigned-to.

And same error occurred  when I run in browser.

I also tried following both options but no luck

0:8000
0.0.0.0:8000 port running successfully in ssh with python manage.py but not in browser.

I checked /etc/network/interfaces this file, following lines already exists there:
      auto lo
      iface lo inet loopback

Anybody has any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daya,
 I try run with port 0:8000 0.0.0.0:8000 but no use.
 Also, /etc/network/interfaces file was perfect.
 But In my case, solution for this problem was to change script file's location.
 I mean to say my django application folder location was /home/ubuntu
 but when I move it to /Var/www it worked.It worked because server is apache2.